# ReSharper 9 Adding menu item action not working

Tags: c#, nuget, resharper, nuget-package, resharper-9.0

Trying to update my resharper extension to work for 9.0, before I was just moving the dll into the plugins directory but now I need to figure out how to get nuget to work...  I've been able to package the files, dll gets included in the nupkg but I think I have some namespace\id something something issues(not very familiar with .net) and it doesn't seem as if my actions.xml is even being read by resharper when I import the nuget package.  The menu item isn't being added. Anwyays if anyone can give me any sort of advice on how to debug  a nuget package or what might be going wrong would really really appreciate as I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<actions>
  <action id="yuval" text="L10N"></action>
  <insert group-id="ReSharper" position="last">
    <action-ref id="yuval" text="About Localization Helper"/>
  </insert>
</actions>
```

AboutAction.cs

```
namespace JetBrains.Resharper.L10N
{
    [Action(Id)]
    public class AboutAction : IExecutableAction
    {
        public const string Id = "yuval";

    public bool Update(IDataContext context, ActionPresentation presentation, DelegateUpdate nextUpdate)
        {    
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(IDataContext context, DelegateExecute nextExecute)
        {
            MessageBox.ShowMessageBox(
              "Localization Helper\nYuval\n\nHelps Localize",
              "About Localization Helper",
              MbButton.MB_OK,
              MbIcon.MB_ICONASTERISK);
        }

    }
}
```

nuget spec

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>JetBrains.Resharper.L10N</id>
    <version>1.0.0.7</version>
    <title>L10N</title>
    <authors>Yuval</authors>
    <owners>UW</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://myurl.com</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://myurl.com</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://myurl.com/logo.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Tool to help localize</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Wave" version="[1.0]" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
<files>
    <file src="..\bin\Debug\JetBrains.Resharper.L10N.dll"
          target="dotFiles\"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way actions are registered has changed in ReSharper 9. It's no longer done with `actions.xml`, but with interfaces on your action class. For example, to add an action to the ReSharper → Tools menu, you would do:

```cs
[Action(ActionId, Id = 1)]
public class AboutAction : IExecutableAction, IInsertLast<ToolsMenu>
{
  public const string ActionId = "yuval";
  // …
}
```

You also need to specify a unique value for `Id`. As of 9.1, this needs to be unique within your own extension (9.0 required it to be unique across the whole installation, including ReSharper itself and any other extensions).

Whenever you change the attributes or interfaces of an action, the extension needs to be reinstalled via nupkg (the actions are statically registered with Visual Studio, in the same way as a standard VS extension), but if just the implementation has changed, you can copy the dlls to the install folder, either manually, or via [a small change to the .csproj](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Extensions/Deployment/LocalInstallation.html#updating-the-extension-locally).

You also need to make sure you've defined a `ZoneMarker` class. This declares that your action belongs to a zone, which is used to enable/disable functionality based on installed features and the current host (e.g. so Visual Studio specific extensions only work in VS and don't get loaded into dotPeek, etc.). You can find out more about [Zones in the devguide](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Platform/Zones.html), with this page providing useful info for [defining a zone marker](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Platform/Zones/HowTo.html).

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/resharper-plugins/3yAm6xqCiNw/cZDeM3IGv38J) should help, too.

Also, it's probably a good idea to name you dll and nupkg something other than `JetBrains.ReSharper.(Whatever)` to prevent any potential clashes with official dlls, and to prevent confusion as to where the dll comes from. The first part of the name is supposed to be your company's name (or personal name).

Comment: How can I define my own menu groups in which I can locate multiple of my menu items? Can I add such a group to the main menu of Visual Studio or at the top level in the ReSharper menu entry?

Comment: Btw... how is it possible to set the "text" of the menu item?

Comment: Ok, it took me some time but I figured it out... I think your example is incorrect. In your case the attribute has to be `[Action(Id, Id = <large number>)]`, right? At least that is the only way I got my action show up in the menu. Please adapt the explanation! I guess renaming the variable in your example would also prevent further confusion...

Comment: Yep, bad choice of constant name. I've renamed it to `ActionId`, as that's the parameter name. For 9.1, the value of `Id` can be any number, as it no longer needs to be unique to the whole installation, just the extension (I *think*, but haven't checked, that you can get away without setting it, too).

Comment: Creating a group requires creating a class that derives from `IAction` and is marked with the `[ActionGroup(…)]` attribute. It requires a group insert style (embedded, submenu, separator) and a unique ID (again, I'm not 100% sure if this can be omitted). You can now use this action (group) as a parameter for the `IInsertLast<TGroup>` type interfaces.

Comment: You can set the text of the menu item via the `ActionAttribute` parameters. One is the `actionId` - a string that identifies the action, as seen in the list of commands for VS' keyboard options, and the second is the text that is displayed. You can also change it dynamically by implementing the `Update` method of either `IExecutableAction` or `IPresentableAction`, and modifying the value in the `ActionPresentation` parameter. (Return `true` to say the action is available, `false` if not)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, you helped me a lot! You should update your post to include all these information though... but I guess an even better idea is to incorporate it directly into the ReSharper dev guide :P